# parsing parenthesized list in python's imaplib

Tags: python, parsing, imap, imaplib

I am looking for simple way to split parenthesized lists that come out of IMAP responses into Python lists or tuples. I want to go from

```
'(BODYSTRUCTURE ("text" "plain" ("charset" "ISO-8859-1") NIL NIL "quoted-printable" 1207 50 NIL NIL NIL NIL))'
```

to

```
(BODYSTRUCTURE, ("text", "plain", ("charset", "ISO-8859-1"), None, None, "quoted-printable", 1207, 50, None, None, None, None))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

pyparsing's nestedExpr parser function parses nested parentheses by default:

```
from pyparsing import nestedExpr

text = '(BODYSTRUCTURE ("text" "plain" ("charset" "ISO-8859-1") NIL NIL "quotedprintable" 1207 50 NIL NIL NIL NIL))'

print nestedExpr().parseString(text)
```

prints:

```
[['BODYSTRUCTURE', ['"text"', '"plain"', ['"charset"', '"ISO-8859-1"'], 'NIL', 'NIL', '"quoted printable"', '1207', '50', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL']]]
```

Here is a slightly modified parser, which does parse-time conversion of integer strings to integers, from "NIL" to None, and stripping quotes from quoted strings:

```
from pyparsing import (nestedExpr, Literal, Word, alphanums, 
    quotedString, replaceWith, nums, removeQuotes)

NIL = Literal("NIL").setParseAction(replaceWith(None))
integer = Word(nums).setParseAction(lambda t:int(t[0]))
quotedString.setParseAction(removeQuotes)
content = (NIL | integer | Word(alphanums))

print nestedExpr(content=content, ignoreExpr=quotedString).parseString(text)
```

Prints:

```
[['BODYSTRUCTURE', ['text', 'plain', ['charset', 'ISO-8859-1'], None, None, 'quoted-printable', 1207, 50, None, None, None, None]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The fact that there's nested tuples makes this impossible with a regex. You'll have to write a parser to denote when you're inside a parenthesis or not.

You could try

```
tuple('(BODYSTRUCTURE ("text" "plain" ("charset" "ISO-8859-1") NIL NIL "quoted-printable" 1207 50 NIL NIL NIL NIL))'.replace("NIL", "None").split(' '))
```

Edit:
Well I got something that works with your example, not sure it's what you want though.

BODYSTRUCTURE needs to be defined somewhere.

```
eval(",".join([a for a in '(BODYSTRUCTURE ("text" "plain" ("charset" "ISO-8859-1") NIL NIL "quoted-printable" 1207 50 NIL NIL NIL NIL))'.replace("NIL", "None").split(' ')]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking out only internal part of the server answer containing actualy the body structure:

```
struct = ('(((("TEXT" "PLAIN" ("CHARSET" "ISO-8859-1") NIL NIL "7BIT" 16 2)'
         '("TEXT" "HTML" ("CHARSET" "ISO-8859-1") NIL NIL "QUOTED-PRINTABLE"'
         ' 392 6) "ALTERNATIVE")("IMAGE" "GIF" ("NAME" "538.gif") '
         '"<538@goomoji.gmail>" NIL "BASE64" 172)("IMAGE" "PNG" ("NAME" '
         '"4F4.png") "<gtalk.4F4@goomoji.gmail>" NIL "BASE64" 754) "RELATED")'
         '("IMAGE" "JPEG" ("NAME" "avatar_airbender.jpg") NIL NIL "BASE64"'
         ' 157924) "MIXED")')
```

Next step is to replace some tokens, what would prepair string to transform into python types:

```
struct = struct.replace(' ', ',').replace(')(', '),(')
```

Using built-in module [compiler](http://docs.python.org/library/compiler.html) to parse our structure:

```
import compiler
expr = compiler.parse(struct.replace(' ', ',').replace(')(', '),('), 'eval')
```

Performing simple recursive function to transform expression:

```
def transform(expression):
    if isinstance(expression, compiler.transformer.Expression):
        return transform(expression.node)
    elif isinstance(expression, compiler.transformer.Tuple):
        return tuple(transform(item) for item in expression.nodes)
    elif isinstance(expression, compiler.transformer.Const):
        return expression.value
    elif isinstance(expression, compiler.transformer.Name):
        return None if expression.name == 'NIL' else expression.name
```

And finally we get the desired result as nested python tuples:

```
result = transform(expr)
print result

(((('TEXT', 'PLAIN', ('CHARSET', 'ISO-8859-1'), None, None, '7BIT', 16, 2), ('TEXT', 'HTML', ('CHARSET', 'ISO-8859-1'), None, None, 'QUOTED-PRINTABLE', 392, 6), 'ALTERNATIVE'), ('IMAGE', 'GIF', ('NAME', '538.gif'), '<538@goomoji.gmail>', None, 'BASE64', 172), ('IMAGE', 'PNG', ('NAME', '4F4.png'), '<gtalk.4F4@goomoji.gmail>', None, 'BASE64', 754), 'RELATED'), ('IMAGE', 'JPEG', ('NAME', 'avatar_airbender.jpg'), None, None, 'BASE64', 157924), 'MIXED')
```

From where we can recognize different headers of body structure:

```
text, attachments = (result[0], result[1:])
```