# Parsing Email BodyStructure in python

Tags: python, parsing, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [parsing parenthesized list in python's imaplib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973963/parsing-parenthesized-list-in-pythons-imaplib)

Python's email package lets you take the full text of an email message and parse it into parts and walk through the various parts. However, is there a library to parse the `BODYSTRUCTURE` response returned by the IMAP protocol into `email.message.Message` parts?

**EDIT:**

The equivalent method in PHP is [`imap_fetchbody()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchstructure.php), which handles the parsing of structure automatically.

**EDIT2**:

This question had been incorrectly closed as a duplicate. It is about parsing the `BODYSTRUCTURE` nested expression into a useful format (such as a dictionary) and not about parsing the raw string into python type. In any case, I ended up rolling my own solution and here's the code for anyone who comes across a similar problem in the future. It is intended to be used together with the `imapclient` library

```
# ----- Parsing BODYSTRUCTURE into parts dictionaries ----- #

def tuple2dict(pairs):
    """get dict from (key, value, key, value, ...) tuple"""
    if not pairs:
        return None
    return dict([(k, tuple2dict(v) if isinstance(v, tuple) else v)
                 for k, v in zip(pairs[::2], pairs[1::2])])

def parse_singlepart(var, part_no):
    """convert non-multipart into dic"""
    # Basic fields for non-multipart (Required)
    part = dict(zip(['maintype', 'subtype', 'params', 'id', 'description', 'encoding', 'size'], var[:7]), part_no=part_no)
    part['params'] = tuple2dict(part['params'])

    # Type specific fields (Required for 'message' or 'text' type)
    index = 7
    if part['maintype'].lower() == 'message' and part['subtype'].lower() == 'rfc822':
        part.update(zip(['envelope', 'bodystructure', 'lines'], var[7:10]))
        index = 10
    elif part['maintype'].lower() == 'text':
        part['lines'] = var[7]
        index = 8

    # Extension fields for non-multipart (Optional)
    part.update(zip(['md5', 'disposition', 'language', 'location'], var[index:]))
    part['disposition'] = tuple2dict(part['disposition'])

    return part

def parse_multipart(var, part_no):
    """convert the multipart into dict"""
    part = { 'child_parts': [], 'part_no': part_no }

    # First parse the child parts
    index = 0
    if isinstance(var[0], list):
        part['child_parts'] = [parse_part(v, ('%s.%d' % (part_no, i+1)).replace('TEXT.', '')) for i, v in enumerate(var[0])]
        index = 1
    elif isinstance(var[0], tuple):
        while isinstance(var[index], tuple):
            part['child_parts'].append(parse_part(var[index], ('%s.%d' % (part_no, index+1)).replace('TEXT.', '')))
            index += 1

    # Then parse the required field subtype and optional extension fields
    part.update(zip(['subtype', 'params', 'disposition', 'language', 'location'], var[index:]))
    part['params'] = tuple2dict(part['params'])
    part['disposition'] = tuple2dict(part['disposition'])

    return part

def parse_part(var, part_no=None):
    """Parse IMAP email BODYSTRUCTURE into nested dictionary

    See http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501#section-6.4.5 for structure of email messages
    See http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501#section-7.4.2 for specification of BODYSTRUCTURE
    """
    if isinstance(var[0], (tuple, list)):
        return parse_multipart(var, part_no or 'TEXT')
    else:
        return parse_singlepart(var, part_no or '1')
```